# pythonでのファイルの開き方について

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

pythonでのファイルの開き方について質問です。

実際のファイルは確認したのに、jupyter-notebookに

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
open(path).readline()
```

と入力しても

```
FileNotFoundError
```

となってしまいます。ちなみに実際のファイルはこれです。
`http://ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt`

どうやったらファイルを正常に開けるか教えてください

Comment: > `http://ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt`
file://ではないのですか？HTTPプロトコルでファイルを取得する場合 `open` ではこのままだと不可能ですが……

Comment: Jupyter notebook をどう起動したかにもよるのですが、カレントディレクトリが合っていないのでは。import os して、os.getcwd() でカレントディレクトリを調べて、os.chdir()で移動すればいいように思います。

Answer (score 1):

> ちなみに実際のファイルはこれです。
>   http://ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt

URLから、データはネットワーク上にあり、そこにアクセスするプロトコールはHTTPであることが分ります。
　だとすればBeautiful Soupなどwebスクレイピングのためのツールを使うのが良いと思います。

拡張子が.txtですから、テキストファイルなのでHTMLのパーザなどは使わなくて済むと思います。

”ch02”だけでは、サーバが特定できません。
”ja.stackoverflow.com”とか"whitehouse.gov"のように、ちゃんとしたホスト名を使ってください。

Comment: > Beautiful Soupなどwebスクレイピングのためのツール

ではファイル取得はできません（HTMLなどをパースするためのツールです）。HTTPスキームファイル取得を行う場合は、 `urllib` や `requests` などのライブラリが良い選択肢になります。